# Dynamic Component issues

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, dynamic

I am creating a component on click of button using $A.createComponent, which is inside a parent component.

```
<aura:component>
<aura:attribute name="displayNoResults" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
...
...
<lightning:button label="Search" />
...
...
{!v.body}
</aura:component>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. If I click the button 1st time, then I need to call the controller
   method to create the component using $A.createComponent. But if I
   click the button 2nd time, do I always have to set the body
   attribute as null before calling my component creation controller method?
2. If the value of attribute displayNoResults
   changes in the parent component, how can I transmit the data of this
   attribute in the child component?

Edited: One more point. The component which is getting created dynamically contains multiple other components. It is acting as a wrapper of components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I click the button 1st time, then I need to call the controller method to create the component using $A.createComponent. But if I click the button 2nd time, do I always have to set the body attribute as null?

No. Once a component goes out of scope, it will eventually be garbage collected. This happens regardless of if you specify a null value first or not.

> If the value of attribute displayNoResults changes in the parent component, how can I transmit the data of this attribute in the child component?

If you use `Component#getReference`, this will happen automatically without any other special considerations:

```
$A.createComponent(
  "ns:sometype",
  { 
    displayNoResults: component.getReference("v.otherBoolean")
  },
  function(result) {
    ...
  });
```

---

> The component which is getting created dynamically contains multiple other components. It is acting as a wrapper of components.

The Lightning Framework will garbage collect everything for you, and `Component#getReference` is still a valid way to get references. In other words, nothing changes.